# Optimizing Django db queries for Viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I recently was tasked to optimize db queries and performance of some of our django rest apis written in drf and was able to successfully use `prefetch_related()` to implement them.

But there is one usecase I have been unable to resolve and looking for support on the same.

Here goes the structure:

**Models.py**

```
class Section(models.Model):
    section_tags = models.ManyToManyField(AssetTag)
    section_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    section_createdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Collection(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="collection_set")
    system_tags = models.ManyToManyField(AssetTag, blank=False, related_name='system_tags_poster_collections')
    card = models.ManyToManyField(Card)

class Card(models.Model):
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(CardTag) # should we deprecate?
    system_tags = models.ManyToManyField(AssetTag, blank=False, related_name='system_tags_poster_cards')
    card_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**views.py**

```
class SectionViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.SectionSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Section.objects.filter(section_status=True, section_expiredate__gte=datetime.now())
        return queryset
```

**serializer.py**

```
class SectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    collection_set = CollectionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class FilteredCollectionSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
    data = data.filter(collection_status=True, collection_expiredate__gte=datetime.now())
    return super(FilteredCollectionSerializer, self).to_representation(data)

class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    card = CardSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    system_tags = AssetTagBadgeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = FilteredCollectionSerializer
        model = Collection
        fields = ('id', 'card', 'system_tags')

class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = CardTagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    system_tags = AssetTagBadgeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    # method_name = 'get_template_id'

    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = ('id', 'card_name', 'card_image', 'card_createdate', 'tag', 'system_tags')


class AssetTagBadgeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AssetTag
        fields = ('id', 'tag_name')
```

I am unable to apply prefetch_related() to get any optimization of the queries on the SectionViewSet since it is sort of a reverse relationship in the Collection Model. Is there any way to optimize calls to db since I see many calls for card__tag and card__system_tags in are application performance monitoring system.

Comment: Have you tried  `Section.objects.prefetch_related('collection_set').filter(section_status=True, section_expiredate__gte=datetime.now())`  in `get_queryset`?

Comment: @Karen this does not work, the performance is the same.

Comment: Can you share `CardSerializer` and `AssetTagBadgeSerializer`?

Comment: @BrianDestura added/updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this as I don't have access to a workspace with python and django at the moment, but have a try with this:

In your view, just do all the prefetch in the view queryset, and run the filter you have on `FilteredCollectionSerializer` here like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch


class SectionViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.SectionSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Section.objects.filter(
            section_status=True, section_expiredate__gte=datetime.now()
        ).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                "collection_set",
                queryset=Collection.objects.filter(
                    collection_status=True, 
                    collection_expiredate__gte=datetime.now(),
                ).prefetch_related(
                    "card__tag",
                    "card__system_tags"
                    "system_tags",
                ),
            ),
        )
        return queryset
```

And then in your serializers, just remove `FilteredCollectionSerializer` in `CollectionSerializer` and avoid running the filter again, which would cancel the prefetch done on the view:

```py
class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    card = CardSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    system_tags = AssetTagBadgeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = ('id', 'card', 'system_tags')
```

Comment: This seems to work for me Brian, queries reduced from over a 1000 to 200. Can you share where I can read more about this optimization?

Comment: Sure! It's all explained on the django docs for `prefetch_related`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related. Also found this blog which might help understand it: https://buildatscale.tech/fixing-n1-query-problem-in-django/